# Finding out what caused my laptop to power down

Tags: suspend

My laptop has been working *mostly* fine with Ubuntu 18.04. But recently (like the last week of March) I have noticed that it always boots up to a fresh login - meaning that it has powered down without hibernating or going into standby. Naturally, this sucks on a production (job) computer!

I am assuming this is due to either
1. a bad driver/firmware update (which has happened recently)
2. some new software in Ubuntu

My power settings don't imply anything else than that the laptop should go into hibernation after some time, and I haven't changed any settings.

How can I find out what is causing this? Is there an event log being written somewhere - other than `syslog`? I can read this from my `syslog` today:

```
Mar 29 14:13:07 diffia9350 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3042]: [4869:4890:0329/141307.593101:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(411)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Mar 29 14:13:09 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 29 14:13:09 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 29 14:13:09 diffia9350 systemd-sleep[9174]: Suspending system...
Mar 29 14:13:09 diffia9350 kernel: [ 4315.853054] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Mar 29 14:43:38 diffia9350 systemd-modules-load[360]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

So it does go into suspend mode. And I can see it waking up half an hour later.

Again:

```
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 NetworkManager[1150]: <info>  [1553872189.3201] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 NetworkManager[1150]: <info>  [1553872189.3203] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 NetworkManager[1150]: <info>  [1553872189.3311] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 gnome-shell[1994]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 gnome-shell[1994]: Failed to set power save mode for output eDP-1: Ikke tilgang
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 wpa_supplicant[1141]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp58s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 29 16:09:49 diffia9350 systemd-sleep[10369]: Suspending system...
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd-modules-load[355]: Inserted module 'lp'
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd-modules-load[355]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd-modules-load[355]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Mar 29 17:38:13 diffia9350 systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
```

Comment: Are you booting from a USB flash key?

Comment: Nope. I am booting from a normal ssd in my XPS 9350.

Comment: When you say "boots up to a fresh login" do you mean "boots up" or "wakes up"? What is the expected behaviour? Do you see any temperature related events in syslog?

Comment: The expected behaviour is that of standby/sleep mode: the computer wakes up, possible with a login screen, but when logged in everything (every program, session state, etc) is exactly as it was before it went into standby/sleep/suspend. Instead, often, when I power it on after it has gone into standby, I get to the login screen, but it's a fresh login. Nothing has been restored. It does work perfectly, though, if I manually execute `pm-hibernate`.

Comment: What other items do you have connected to this laptop? USB devices? 2nd screen? Etc? Show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: When this has happened recently, it has been running on battery power without any peripherals (with a full battery). I can get the listing later.

Comment: Check my answer and report back to @heynnema

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you have current BIOS in your laptop. Go to the manufacturer's web site to verify.

---

If your battery is removable, remove it, disconnect AC power, and hold down the power button for 15 seconds. This will reset the power manager. Reconnect all power and see if the problem is resolved.

If your battery is not removable, then disconnect AC power, leave the computer turned on and not sleeping/hibernating, and let the battery drain to zero. Once the computer turns off, hold down the power button for 15 seconds. Reconnect the AC power. Turn computer back on and let it recharge the battery, and recheck operation.